# What is the meaning of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: notation

I know that $\mathbb{R}$ represents the set of all real numbers. But what does $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, ..., $\mathbb{R}^n$ mean?

Comment: $X^n$ is the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $X$.

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product in "n-ary Cartesian power" paragraph.

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but possibly of interest: [What is the definition of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376563/what-is-the-definition-of-mathbb-rn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all real numbers. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the cartesian product of $n$ many $\mathbb{R}$'s. It's the set of tuples $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ where each $x_i$ is a real number.